# PowerMockito and static methods

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to test a utility class with bunch of static methods. I am writing test for a method that calls another two static methods. On the first static method call mocking seem to work but it disregards second expectation and calls real method. Any idea? I tried providing second PowerMock.spy(Utils.class) before second expectation but no luck. Any idea how to get around this?

here is the sample code.

```
    package com.personal.test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Utils {

    public static String testUtilOne() {
        System.out.println("Static method one");
        return "methodone";
    }

    public static void testUtilsTwo(String s1, String s2, String s3) throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("Throw an exception");
    }

    public static void testUtilsThree() throws TestException {
        try {
            String s = testUtilOne();
            testUtilsTwo("s1", s, "s3");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new TestException("there was an exception", ex);
        }
    }

    public static class TestException extends Exception {
        public TestException() {
            super();
        }
        public TestException(String message, Exception cause) {
            super(message, cause);
        }
    }
}


    package com.personal.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import com.personal.test.Utils.TestException;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Utils.class})
public class UtilsTest {

    @Test
    public void testMethodThreeWrapsException() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(Utils.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Utils.class, "testUtilOne").thenReturn("This is coming from test");
        PowerMockito.spy(Utils.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Utils.class, "testUtilsTwo", Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()).thenThrow(new IOException("Exception from test"));
        try {
            Utils.testUtilsThree();
        } catch (TestException ex) {
            Assert.assertTrue(ex.getCause() instanceof IOException);
            Assert.assertEquals("Exception from test", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for the record: only only only use the *Power* frameworks for static mocking if you have to. Most of the time when people are asking for Powermock ... that is because they created hard/impossible-to-test code; and they think using Powermock will fix that. Nope, it wont. The real answer is to apply good OO techniques and to not use Powermock ;-.)

Answer (score 3):

Just in-case if any one is interested, After spending a whole day trying I finally got around this problem. I first staticMocked my Utils class (this will mock all the static methods) than asked mock to call real method for testUtilsThree call.
Changes are as below.

```
        package com.personal.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import com.personal.test.Utils.TestException;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Utils.class})
public class UtilsTest {

    @Test
    public void testMethodThreeWrapsException() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Utils.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Utils.class, "testUtilOne").thenReturn("This is coming from test");
        PowerMockito.when(Utils.class, "testUtilsTwo", Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()).thenThrow(new IOException("Exception from test"));
        PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(Utils.class, "testUtilsThree");
        try {
            Utils.testUtilsThree();
        } catch (TestException ex) {
            Assert.assertTrue(ex.getCause() instanceof IOException);
            Assert.assertEquals("Exception from test", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to suggest use [ExpectedException](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) instead try catch block to assert exception.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, I used try catch because downstream code throws three different exceptions that are wrapped into a custom exception that my sample code doesn't show. So depending an what is GIVEN down stream code will throw different exception.